# Check and filter for duplicates when sending curl requests with Flask

Tags: python

I am building a Flask server and verifying host-name to be unique and the IP address to not overlap with another IP when sending curl requests.
The POST requests look like this:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/hosts --request POST -d '[{"address": "1.2.3.4", "hostname": "test1", "routes": "1.2.3.1/16"}, {"address": "1.2.3.4", "hostname": "test2", "routes": "5.1.2.5/16"}]' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

The code looks like this:

```
def put_hosts():
content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    
with open('example.json', 'r') as config_file:
    data = json.load(config_file)
    for i in content:
        data.append(i)
    

with open('example.json', 'w') as config_file:
    json.dump(data, config_file, sort_keys = True, indent = 4,
        ensure_ascii = False)
    return jsonify(data), 201
```

At the moment everything works, except if the user adds two identical IP addresses or names, they are both saved as a duplicate. I want to filter these duplicates when sending the request.
If the user gives two identical IP addresses I want to return an error. I tried fixing this with:

```
lines = config_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.rstrip() == "{} {}".format(host['address'], host['hostname']):
            duplicate = True
```

but with no success. Any idea how to make that check so they dont overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in many ways.
If you want to remove the duplicates automatically - use a dictionary:

```
In [1]: a = [{"address": "1.2.3.4", "hostname": "test1", "routes": "1.2.3.1/16"}, {"address": "1.2.3.4", "hostname": "test2", "routes": "5.1.2.5/16"}]

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
[{'address': '1.2.3.4', 'hostname': 'test1', 'routes': '1.2.3.1/16'},
 {'address': '1.2.3.4', 'hostname': 'test2', 'routes': '5.1.2.5/16'}]

In [3]: {each['address']: each for each in a}
Out[3]: 
{'1.2.3.4': {'address': '1.2.3.4',
  'hostname': 'test2',
  'routes': '5.1.2.5/16'}}
```

Now you have a dict where the keys are the unique ipaddresses and the value is the entire json which holds that ipaddress. Duplicates are removed automatically as dicts cannot have duplicate keys.

If you want to return an error, collect all the ip addresses and check if there are duplicates. After collecting create a set of the result and compare the lengths. Set will remove all duplicates. So if there are dupes, the length will not match.

```
In [5]: [each['address'] for each in a]
Out[5]: ['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.4']

In [6]: set([each['address'] for each in a])
Out[6]: {'1.2.3.4'}

In [7]: len(set([each['address'] for each in a])) == len([each['address'] for each in a])
Out[7]: False
```

Comment: content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    if len(set([each['address'] for each in content])) == [each['address'] for each in content] == False:
        return jsonify({'Error': 'IP address or hostname overlap'}). if it is like this content is undefined so it does not work.

Comment: How is ur content undefined ? If your json is being read from the request correctly it cannot be undefined.